# Time Complexity Recursion

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity

I have this recursive function:
$$ 
F(n) = \left\{
\begin{array}{l l}
F(n-2) + 10 F\big(\lfloor\frac{n}{6}\rfloor\big)^2 + 6 F\big(\lfloor \frac{n}{7} \rfloor \big) + \frac{n^4}{5} & \text{if } n > 1\\
2 & \text{otherwise}\\
\end{array} \right. 
$$

And I need to calculate its time complexity. Could you please guide me on how to do it? I assume time grows exponentially, maybe it is $ O(3^n)$  because each time this function calls itself 3 times more? (Given we implement this by simple recursion)

Comment: Does $F$ only take integer? Does $n/6$ and $n/7$ need to be integer? If it does only take integers, then there might be some point not defined, but if it does not, then this recursive formulae alone is not enough to well-define the $F$

Comment: That's a good question, and honestly, I don't know.  This function was near a Fibonacci recursive function on my learning material, which only takes integers, so I assume this one should also take integers only.

Comment: But then, for example, $F(36)$ is not defined, because $36/7$ is not an integer. And then $F(38)$ is also not defined, since it needs $F(38-2) = F(36)$. Of course, $F$ is not defined on $1,2,3,4,5,6,7$ etc. you'll find lots of points undefined. Essentially you see this sequence is mostly not defined.

Comment: What if I just floor it in such cases? So  **F(36)** would just become **36/7=5** ?

Comment: yea that could be. Posted an answer based on this

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If we take the floor of $n/6$ and $n/7$, $O(3^n)$ looks too high to me.

One straight-forward algorithm is to calculate every point starting from $1$ to $n$ (and store all the results in an array), and then you get complexity of $O(n)$

**EDIT**

If you brutal force by implementing this using simple recursion approach, yes, it is $O(3^n)$, because you cannot re-use any results you calculated when arriving each single point of $F$.

In that case, for each $F(n)$, you need to recurse for $O(n)$ layers, and within each layer, you spawn three function calls that each will spawn another three function calls for the next layer of recursion calls. Thus it is $O(3^n)$

Comment: Yes, I know that this recursive algorithm is not efficient, but that's the whole point of my work. I have to compare recursive function and the same problem solved using dynamic programming techniques ( basically memorizing all of the previous values ). [link](http://imgur.com/a/hvKGa) that's a graph I made using this recursion. You can clearly see it's an exponential grow. (X is **n** and Y is time in **ms** )

Comment: @Daniel alright, you did not mention in your question we need to solve this recursive function using recursion though. And if you write your code in recursion, the answer is yes

Comment: Yeap, sorry about that. Here is a code I've used for both of the ways if you are interested [Code](https://pastebin.com/vFy8UFZ0). The dynamic one was a lot faster.

Comment: @Daniel yep, saw you code. Nice, you laid out both two solutions. I've updated my answer accordingly.